# Link two Projects in Visual Studio on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, linker

I have a Remote Solution for my Raspberry Pi (A remote Linux system) in Visual Studio Community 2017 which consists of two C++ projects.
As Project_B is dependent on Project_A. I added the suiting project dependency under *Solution->Properties->Common Properties->Project Dependencies*.
All the includes from Project A in Project B declared as following:

```
#include "../Project_A/header.h"
```

(They should be correct as it compiles)

When I build Project_B Project_A compiles and is linked (according to the output view) and Project_B is compiled but the linker crashes as it cannot find the definitions of the functions from Project_A.
Sometimes, the whole IDE crashes and needs a restart.

Compiling and linking only Project_A works fine.
As a workaround I have copied all files from Project_A to Project_B and modified the includes accordingly and removed the project dependency.

Like that, it works.

However I would like to have an working, clean solution for linking two project on a remote linux system in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4-Apr
Thinking about this, I wonder whether I need to take a step back.

A Visual Studio project takes a bunch of source files and creates one (we'll leave it simple for now) target, e.g. an executable. It also creates several intermediates along the way, most importantly the object files.

So how do you use the funtionality of one project in another? The simplest way is source include which works just like you've done with the headers, add the sources from *projectB* to *projectA*. Not the most efficient solution and it can get messy but it will work.
The most common approach is to build *projectB* into a library. Then *projectA*, which creates the executable, links to the *projectB* library.
To create *projectB*'s library, set the project type to static library and have projectA link to it;  this is what my original answer addressed.

===============

`Solution->Properties->Common Properties->Project Dependencies` allows you to specify the build order, i.e. *projectA* depends on *projectB* so *projectB* should be built first. It does not create cross-project references for compiler and linker.

You must tell *projectA* where to find the headers and binaries of *projectB* on the Pi. In the case of headers you can, as you have done, use relative paths but it would be more general to specify the location of *projectB* files in `Additional Include Directories` under `C/C++ - General` in the VS project properties.

For libraries, you must specify `Library Dependencies` under `Linker - Input` in the project properties and `Additional Library Directories` under `Linker - General`. Alternatively, for projects in the same solution, you can add a `Reference` to *projectB* under *projectA*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: It works and seems to be a solid solution. However, there is still one Problem: I have to write the paths plainy (e.g.'/home/pi/projects/solution/projectA/bin/ARM/Debug') and cannot use '$(RemoteRootDir)/$(SolutionName)/projectA/bin/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)' even though it is the exact same path in the VisualStudio Property Preview.

Comment: Parameter expansion leaves something to be desired, however this:
%24(echo $(RemoteRootDir)/projectA/bin/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)) should do what you want. Look at the build log to see the substitution that has been performed and adjust if required. %24 is a $ character which has to be passed thru to the Linux remote.

Comment: This didn't completely work out for me, but the Platform and Configiguration Parameters did work what should be enough for my purposes: '/home/pi/projects/$(SolutionName)/projectA/bin/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)/'. Tank you again for your great and quick help.